# Convert datatable to private List<List<string>>?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable

Any fast way to convert a datatable to `List<List<string>>` ?

right now i am doing

```
for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= stats.EndRowIndex; rowIndex++)
{
    List<string> lstOneRowElements = new List<string>();
    for (int colIndex = 1; colIndex <= stats.EndColumnIndex; colIndex++)
    {                                
        lstOneRowElements.Add(excelDoc.GetCellValueAsString(rowIndex, colIndex).Trim());
    }

    lstAllData.Add(lstOneRowElements);
}
```

where

```
private List<List<string>> lstAllData { get; set; }
```

any better way to do it fast ?

Comment: @Soner Thnaks for editing

Comment: Formatting is your friend `;)`

Comment: What type is stats? Probably not a .NET DataTable as I see no EndRowIndex property on that type. Is it from http://help.syncfusion.com/cr/cref_files/silverlight/pdf/html/9d7ce914-d164-cd37-d41a-10ddcc6584ea.htm, or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a DataTable (see comment Mithon) then you can try this

```
var q = from row in dt.AsEnumerable()
        select row.ItemArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList<string>();

var y = q.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for simplification ...you rocks :)

Comment: Why this `var y = q.ToList();` line ? You can add.ToList() in first line !!